# Express server not working after adding express-flash middleware

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, node-modules, passport-local

I am using passport.js and it's local strategy to implement a login system in my project.

**I want to show the user about username or password being incorrect** and I'm using `express-flash` for it.
After adding the flash middleware, the server is not working. When I comment out the `app.use(flash)`, the server works normally.

Here are the imported packages and middlewares :

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const passport = require('passport')
const session = require('express-session')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const flash = require('express-flash')
const User = require('./models/userSchema')

//middlewares
app.use(cookieParser('secret'))
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}));
app.use(flash)
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Here are the versions of the dependencies, if it helps :

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.20",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
  }
```

Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Not working is not an error message. What is the output from console?

Comment: There is no output. No view is loading. The page keeps loading forever. @elsololobo

Comment: Hi. I just figured out that I was doing `app.use(flash)` when I was supposed to do `app.use(flash())`. The app was not able to recognize the former one and was stuck there.

Comment: The console was not giving any error. Actually, when I was going to localhost:3000 it kept spinning for forever and beyond